# Objects as keys in a HashMap - how to reference them (java)

Tags: java, hashmap

I am currently working on a small project simulating a game. Each `Player` object has an inventory which is a `HashMap<Item, Integer>` where the Integer is the quantity of that Item.

I am currently trying to write a method in the `Player` class, that allows the player to buy an `Item` from a `Shop`, if the Player have enough `Coins` in their inventory. Each `Player` starts with 50 `Coins` in their inventory.

Although, when I am trying to acces the coins in the players inventory (using `inventory.get(coins)`), I get an "coins cannot be resolved to a variable error".

CONSTRUCTOR

```
private String name;
    private HashMap<Item, Integer> inventory;
    private String location;


public Player (String name){
        this.name = name;
        location = "Home";

        inventory = new HashMap<>();

        Resource coins = new Resource("Coins", 1, 1);
        Tool pickaxe = new Tool("Pickaxe", 100, 100);
        Tool axe = new Tool("Axe", 100, 100);
        Tool shovel = new Tool("Shovel", 100, 100);
        Crop turnip = new Crop("Turnip", 20, "Spring");

        this.inventory.put(coins, 50);
        this.inventory.put(pickaxe, 1);
        this.inventory.put(axe, 1);
        this.inventory.put(shovel, 1);
        this.inventory.put(turnip, 10);
    }
```

METHOD THAT FAILS

```
public void buyItemPierre(Shop pierres, Item item){
        if (location.equals("Pierres")){

            if (pierres.getForSale().containsKey(item)){
                
                if (inventory.get(**coins**) >= pierres.getForSale().get(item)){ // ERROR HERE

                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Sorry, that item is not for sale here");
            }

        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You have to visit Pierres before you can buy anything from there!");
        }
    }
```

I've tried instantiating the objects in the main method, although I get the same error. There must be something that I don't get regarding how to reference objects as keys in a HashMap... How else can I check if the player has enough `coins`? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This could be fixed by proper usable of variables, but honestly: don't. Don't use Objects like them as Map keys. They don't bring you any advantage. Use something static like a String "coins" or a own Enum. Much more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `coins` as a local variable in the constructor.

```
        Resource coins = new Resource("Coins", 1, 1);
```

So as soon as the constructor is complete, that variable goes away. You still have the *object* as a key in the map, but if you want to use the `coins` variable to look it up in the map, you have to declare it as a member (outside the constructor).

```
private Resource coins= new Resource("Coins", 1, 1);
```

Comment: Ah okay that does make sense! 
But how can I then add a new object to the inventory and access it later? Should I then declare that as a member too?

Comment: Just like you have a `buyItemPierre` method, you need a `addItem` method so you can add items to the map.

Comment: Aside: the type of map you are using is also called a "multiset" or a "bag":https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset

Comment: I would create a wrapper class around `Item` to hold the count. `public class InventoryItem { Item item; Integer count; ...constructors and setter}` And then declare your map to hold these, indexed by a string. `private Map<String, InventoryItem> inventory=new HashMap<>();` Then, in your constructor, use `inventory.put("Coins", new InventoryItem(new Resource("Coins",1,1), 50);`

Comment: Thank you so much for all your responses! Really appreciated